# CAML Query to search comma separated values similar to SQL query

Tags: caml-query, caml

Instead of below query, is possible to write dynamic CAML query for below CAML query. because below query will not work for dynamic data:

```
<Where>
    <Or>
        <Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='VehicleLine' />
                <Value Type='Text'>Test1</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Or>       
    <Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='VehicleLine' />
                <Value Type='Text'>Test2</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Or>       
    <Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='VehicleLine' />
                <Value Type='Text'>Test3</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Or>       
    </Or>
</Where>
```

I cannot find a close example for what I am trying to achieve, which is to check multiple fields for multiple values. Yes, I have looked on SO already for my answer, including this one: Need help on building dynamic CAML Query.

With that said, if it is possible, how can the following SQL-like query be written in CAML?

```
DECLARE @VehicleLines VARCHAR(50)='Test1','Test2','Test3'; --it can anything (based on user selection)

SELECT * FROM Master WHERE VehicleLine IN (@VehicleLines)
```

I want to use CAML query in javascript to fetch data from list.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a CSV, equals will never work.  Consider using `<Contains>`:

```
<Where>
  <Or>
    <Or>
      <Contains>
        <FieldRef Name='VehicleLine' />
        <Value Type='Text'>Test1</Value>
      </Contains>
      <Contains>
        <FieldRef Name='VehicleLine' />
        <Value Type='Text'>Test2</Value>
      </Contains>
    </Or>
    <Contains>
      <FieldRef Name='VehicleLine' />
      <Value Type='Text'>Test3</Value>
    </Contains>
  </Or>
</Where>
```

Regarding dynamic building of Caml, there are many libraries that will do that for you.  I've always used [roboCAML](https://github.com/iOnline247/roboCAML) for such requirements.